# autoasignar valor

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente al momento de auto asignar un valor en los registros de una tabla.

Yo lo puedo asignar en orden a lo que deseo, pero al momento que debe de empezar a asignar nuevamente para que tenga una misma carga de trabajo todo los usuarios me muestra 0.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me ingresa despues del 9.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los registros de la tabla users esta conformada de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parte del codigo:

```
$com = $db->query("SELECT id_users,COUNT(id_users) FROM trabajo GROUP BY id_users HAVING COUNT(id_users) ORDER BY  COUNT(id_users) asc, id_users desc limit 1 ");
while ($opt = $com->fetch_array()) {
     $idusers = $opt['id_users'];
     $contador = $opt['COUNT(id_users)'];
}
if (!isset($contador)) {
         $idusers = 0;
    }

$pro = $db->query("SELECT status, MAX(id) AS maximo, MIN(id) minimo FROM users WHERE status = 1 AND id > '".$idusers."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
if ($rwx = $pro->fetch_array()) {
     $maximo = $rwx['maximo'];
     $minimo = $rwx['minimo'];
        echo $id2 = $minimo;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, no se entiende tu pregunta. Tal vez se relaciona con otra cosa que preguntaste pero... no lo sé con certeza.

Comment: creo que deberías de revisar la estructura de tu tabla, mira si al campo no le colocaste algo como un tipo tinyint de tamaño 1

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar, @Alfabravo lo que deseo hacer es evaluar el usuario que tiene mayor carga de trabajo y asignarle al proximo. Por el momento recorre todo desde el 1 al 9 que es el registro que tengo de usuario pero al empezar nuevamente con el 1 cae en un bucle si lo asigno manual el valor 2 sigue hasta el 9 y nuevamente cae en un bucle.

Comment: @MauEspaña el campo tinyint lo tiene el campo de status, en la tabla de usuario pero en la tabla de trabajo (donde quiero asignarle el trabajo a los usuario) el campo es int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo

```
// contar las veces que se respite el id_users 
$com = $db->query("SELECT id_users,COUNT(id_users) FROM trabajo GROUP BY id_users HAVING COUNT(id_users) ORDER BY COUNT(id_users) ");
while ($opt = $com->fetch_array()) {
     $idusers = $opt['id_users'];
     $contador = $opt['COUNT(id_users)'];
     $valor = $opt['id_users'];
}
// en caso de que no traiga valor asignarle 0
    if (!isset($contador)) {
        $idusers = 0;
        $valor = 0;
    } 
// saber el id_users que esta activo y indicarle que sea el proximo
    $pro = $db->query("SELECT status, MAX(id) AS maximo, MIN(id) minimo FROM users WHERE status = 1 AND id > '".$idusers."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    if ($rwx = $pro->fetch_array()) {
        $maximo = $rwx['maximo'];
// Si el id_users es igual o menor  a id que me trae el contador 
        if ($valor <= $maximo) {            
            $minimo = $rwx['minimo'];
            $id2 = $minimo;
        } else { ////////// en caso contrario empieza desde 1 
            $id2 = '1';
        }
            
    }
```

De esta forma evalua la tabla y me dice cual es el mayor y puedo asignarle automaticamente el siguiente.